# Prove weak convergence of probability distributions given pointwise convergence of their density

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $0 < M < \infty$, and let $f, f_1, f_2,\dots : [0; 1] \rightarrow [0; M]$ be Borel-measurable functions with $\int_0^1f d\lambda = \int_0^1f_n d\lambda = 1$. Suppose $\forall x \in [0; 1] : lim_n f_n(x) = f(x)$. Define probability measures $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2, \dots$ by $\mu(A) = \int_A f d\lambda$ and $\mu_n(A) = \int_A f_n d\lambda$ for Borel $A \subseteq [0; 1]$. Prove that $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$.

This would be fairly easy if $f_n$ and $f$ were Riemann-integrable: in this case $\forall x \in [0; 1] : \mu(\{x\}) = 0$ we have that $\mu_n([0; x]) = \int_0^x f_n d\lambda = \int_0^x f_n(t) dt \rightarrow \int_0^x f(t) dt = \int_0^x f d\lambda = \mu([0; x])$ by the properties of Riemann integrals, and the weak convergence immediately following. But how can this be proven in general case?

Comment: How comes that $\int_0^x f_n(t) dt \rightarrow \int_0^x f(t) dt$ if the functions are Riemann-integrable? Usually in that case it is needed the uniform convergence...

Comment: @Netchaiev my classical analysis is really rusty, so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm mistaken here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_i$ values are in $[0,M]$, the dominated convergence theorem gives you already the result : let $x\in [0,1]$, and define $g_i(t):= 1_{[0,x]}(t)f_i(t)$ then $g_i(t)\rightarrow 1_{[0,x]}(t)f(t)$ and $|g_i|\leq M$. The dominated convergence theorem gives then :
$$ \int g_i(t) dt \rightarrow \int g(t) dt$$
So, in other words : 
$$ \mu_i([0,x])=\int 1_{[0,x]}(t)f_i(t) dt =\int g_i(t) dt\rightarrow \int g(t) dt = \int 1_{[0,x]}(t)f(t) dt=\mu([0,x]).$$

Comment: I didn't realize the dominated convergence theorem can be applied here to "naked" probability distributions, as the book I'm using rather introduces it as a theorem about expected values of random variables. Indeed, $f$ and $f_n$ can be considered random variables on the Lebesgue probability triple, so this answers my question. Thanks!